# AsyncTask #1 an error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup

Here is my code and log message

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.raspored);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    url = bundle.getString("url");
    new FetchWebsiteData().execute();
}


private class FetchWebsiteData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String eles = "";

    /*@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Raspored.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }*/

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
             // Connect to website
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Get the html document title
            //websiteTitle = document.title();
            Element elementsByTag = document.body();
            Element tablica = elementsByTag.getElementsByTag("table").get(9).getElementsByTag("td").get(4);
            Elements redak = tablica.getElementsByTag("ul");
            eles = redak.text().toString();

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set title into TextView
        TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbl_txt);
        txttitle.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        //txttitle.setText(websiteTitle + "\n" + eles);
        String ele = eles.replace(" ", "\n");
        arr_linkText.add(ele);
        for(String temp : arr_linkText) {
            txttitle.append(temp);
        }     
        //mProgressDialog.dismiss();  
    }

  }
}
```

Log:

```
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() 
10-30 21:04:54.554:E/AndroidRuntime(27047):atandroid.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:299)    
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):    at com.project.busme.Raspored$FetchWebsiteData.doInBackground(Raspored.java:52)
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):    at com.project.busme.Raspored$FetchWebsiteData.doInBackground(Raspored.java:1)
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):    ... 5 more
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Make sure you included all dependencies of Jsoup in your project.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup 10-30 21:04:54.554: E/AndroidRuntime(27047):`

Comment: What does that mean? I added jsoup.jar file in project

Comment: check your imports correctly and also, trying a clean build and restarting wouldnt kill time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure jsoup jar is in class path?
Make sure jsoup jar is added in your apk.

Comment: I Have to Right click on the project name > Properties > Java Build Path > tab Libraries then click on button Add External jars.
Select jar's path from your directory where you had downloaded jsoup-1.8.1.jar.
    After adding jar go to next tab Order and export and select checkbox jsoup-1.8.1.jar, click ok,clean build your project and then run.